# Deploying app using maven 3.3 and Jenkins against weblogic 12.1.3

Tags: maven, deployment, jenkins, weblogic12c

There is a maven multi module project with a parent pom, which has:

```
<packaging>pom</packaging>
```

and below the list of modules.

Each module has on its pom:

```
<packaging>jar</packaging>
```

or

```
<packaging>war</packaging>
```

When I build the central app on a local machine using maven with the configuration to deploy on a remote server, it deploys successfully the individual targets on the server.

In Jenkins I installed Maven plugin and Weblogic Deployment plugin with the wlfullclient.jar. However when I try to deploy from Jenkins the whole project I get the error:

```
Deploying the main artifact test-1.0-SNAPSHOT.pom
org.apache.maven.artifact.deployer.ArtifactDeploymentException: Failed 
to deploy artifacts/metadata: Cannot access  with type default using the
available connector factories: WagonRepositoryConnectorFactory
```

I added Apache Wagon dependency in case that was causing the error but with no luck.

I also checked that test-1.0-SNAPSHOT.pom exists in /var/lib/jenkins/.m2

When trying to deploy, during pre-integration phase, with the maven-weblogic-plugin version 12.1.3-0-0 the followin error occurs:

```
[ERROR] Failed to execute goal com.oracle.weblogic:weblogic-maven-plugin:
12.1.3-0-0:deploy (wls-deploy) on project test:
java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: The file, 
'test\target\test-1.0-SNAPSHOT.pom', does not exist.
```

and indeed it does not exist, and seems like a similar problem.

When I tried to deploy with Jenkins an individual module of the project everything run smoothly and deployed successfully.

```
[WeblogicDeploymentPlugin] - DEPLOYING ARTIFACT...
$ /var/lib/jenkins/tools/hudson.model.JDK/jdk1.8.0_66/bin/java -Xms256M
-Xmx256M -cp /home/git-client/wlfullclient.jar weblogic.Deployer -debug 
-stage -remote -verbose -upload -name testModule -source /var/lib/jenkins
/.m2/repository/test/testModule/1.0-SNAPSHOT/testModule-1.0-SNAPSHOT.war
-targets AdminServer -adminurl t3://10.***:7001 -user *** -password ***
-deploy
[WeblogicDeploymentPlugin] - ARTIFACT DEPLOYED SUCCESSFULLY.
```

Does anyone have an idea what could cause such behaviour?